# Close unused Netty threads

Tags: websocket, netty, wso2-esb

I have deployed WebSocket project on WSO2 ESB and I noticed that each time, when new client connects to the websocket, then WSO2 creates around 8 ports (8 threads). 
The problem is that even if client (previously connected to the WebSocket) will close WebSocket connection then threads are not closed (so it means that ports are not closed as well). Since my application will serve around 10'000 customers, it cannot be possible to leave open ports when client disconnects.

I did some research and debugging and found out the piece of code that is responsible for channel creation (it is wso2 esb code that invokes Netty server code):

```
final EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
handler = new WebSocketClientHandler(WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(uri,
        WebSocketVersion.V13,
        contentType != null ? SubprotocolBuilderUtil.contentTypeToSyanapeSubprotocol(contentType) : null,
        false,
        new DefaultHttpHeaders()));
Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                if (sslCtx != null) {
                    p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), host, port));
                }
                p.addLast(new HttpClientCodec(), new HttpObjectAggregator(8192),
                        new WebSocketFrameAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE), handler);
            }
        });

Channel ch = b.connect(uri.getHost(), port).sync().channel();
ch.closeFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
        removeChannelHandler(sourceIdentifier, getClientHandlerIdentifier(uri));
    }
});
```

Like I understand `EventLoopGroup` stores list of threads that open ports for WebSocket connection. 
I would like to close all threads (ports) related to the WebSocket connection when client is disconnecting.

Please, let me know what is the best way to do it. I will appreciate any code example.

---

UPDATE
Above code of WSO2, opens many ports for client requests. It handles WebSocket channel creation however *it does not close any port* when channel is closed. 
How can I close open ports when channel is closing?

Comment: Your code should create the EventLoopGroup once, and you can add an IdleStateHandler to close abandoned (idle) channels, but I'm not quite sure whether it's your code or not

Comment: @EranHarel, no it's not my code, it's ootb code of wso2 esb

Comment: @EranHarel, could you explain what do you mean? Any code examples?

Comment: Code that uses async IO, or netty for that matter doesn't need to create a thread per request. You usually create an executor containing a thread per core - that's the EventLoopGroup. You can see examples for the IdleStateHandler here: https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html

Comment: If you want a full answer, you will need to improve your question BTW